# Is there a way to leak parent css to child components in Vue?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I've got `App.vue`:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <p class="text">Hello World</p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import ParentComponent from '../components/ParentComponent'

export default {
    components: {
        ParentComponent
    }
}
</script>
```

And then I have `ParentComponent`:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <p class="text">Hello World</p>
        <ChildComponent />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import ChildComponent from '../ChildComponent'

export default {
    components: {
        ChildComponent
    }
}
</script>

<style>
    .text {
        font-size: 30px
    }
</style>
```

`ChildComponent`:

```
<template>
    <p class="text">Hello World</p>
</template>

<script>
export default {

}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

Now, whatever styles I have in `ParentComponent`, I want the child component to have that style as well.

However, I don't want `App.vue` to have that style. Also if `ChildComponent` has any other components, then they should inherit the style of `ParentComponent` as well. Like `ParentComponent` is the style provider.

I really don't have any code to show. I just want to know if this is possible and how?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create an css class in the parent component with the style you want to have the children use. Then you simply use the class in a child.

The example you have is actually working as how you want it to be, as long as the child-component indeed nested as a child in the parent component.

What we do in our firm is that we always wrap components with a class with the same name as the component name. This makes it really obvious what you are styling if you are doing some weird parent type styling.

**ParentComponent:**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <p class="text">Hello World</p>
        <ChildComponent />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import ChildComponent from '../ChildComponent'

export default {
    components: {
        ChildComponent
    }
}
</script>

<style>
    .some-class-name {
     /*...*/
    }
    .text {
        font-size: 30px
    }
</style>
```

**ChildComponent:**

```
<template>
    <div class="some-class-name">
        <p class="text">Hello World</p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {

}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

Comment: I mean in general use like importing bootstrap in ParentComponent and using that bootstrap css only in child components.

Comment: Well, this depends on what you mean by "only in child components". 
If you import bootstrap in the parent component, it will naturally also be applied to itself *and* all children. You could use [sass imports and scope them](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import#nesting) inside a class you only apply to children, if you do not want the parent including the css to also get the styling on itself.